# htaccess rewrite w/ godaddy

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

trying my .htaccess page to rewrite this url

```
www.mywebsite.com/view.php?2012/this-is-page.html
```

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/view.php/2012/this-is-page.html
```

Where "view.php" is the template... I just don't like the "view.php?"

Finally got this CMS to work using the "?" after "view.php" instead of "/"  -- now, how do I get it to rewrite this in the browser URL window ?

So far, I have:

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from view.php?2012/this-is-page.html to view/2012/this-is-page.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+view\.php\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteCond ^ view/%1? [L,R]

# internal forward from view/2012/this-is-page.html to view.php?2012/this-is-page.html
RewriteCond ^view/(.+)$ view.php?$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```